# Importing a typed object from another repository in a multi repo project Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import an object from another repository in a multi repo project, typescript is arguing that the type in not the same while I'm sure it is the same:

Type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/Users/user/javascript/packages/@shared/node_modules/knex/types/index")<any, unknown[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'.
```

Like you can see the compiler is referencing the type of the imported object using the full path to node_module and comparing this to the same time but in the node_module of current folder, to find they are not the same.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The default export of knex/types/index is the namespace knex.

```
export declare namespace knex {
  class QueryBuilder {
    static extend(
      methodName: string,
      fn: <TRecord extends {} = any, TResult = unknown[]>(
        this: Knex.QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>,
        ...args: any[]
      ) => Knex.QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>
    ): void;
}
//... at the end of the file
export default knex;
```

But if you do a direct import with `import Knex from "knex"` it references this type of code from knex/types/index:

```
export interface Knex<TRecord extends {} = any, TResult = unknown[]> 
  extends Knex.QueryInterface<TRecord, TResult>, events.EventEmitter {
    //... code
}
```

So those two imports in the error message are actually not referring to the same type. This would be the correct import:

```
import("/Users/user/javascript/packages/@shared/node_modules/knex/types/index").Knex<any, unknown[]>
```